# Prove of infinite ways of writing $n$ as $\pm 1^2\pm 2^2\pm....\pm k^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, infinite-groups

Prove that for each integer $n$, there are infinite ways to represent $n=\pm 1^2\pm 2^2\pm....\pm k^2$ where $k$ is a positive integer and $+,-$ are adjustable

Comment: For future reference, we don't take kindly to begging, "help!!", and "only answers please!!".

Comment: I am really really sorry....I am new in stack exchange........I will give such titles in future.....

Comment: I will not give such titles in future......(not missing in the previous comment...typo)

Comment: You should be able to improve the Question by adding some context.  Where did this problem arise, and/or what makes it interesting to you?  What did you think of for attacking the problem, and/or what difficulties did you encounter in following such an approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma 1** : For every $m$ a natural number, we have:

$$ 0 = (m)^2 - (m+1)^2 - (m+2)^2 + (m+3)^2 - (m+4)^2 + (m+5)^2 + (m+6)^2 - (m+7)^2 $$

(The proof of this follows from lemma 2 !)

**Lemma 2** : For every natural number $m$ we have :

$$ 4 = (m)^2 - (m+1)^2 - (m+2)^2 + (m+3)^2 $$

Proof: Simple algebra.

---

At first, suppose $n$ to be an arbitrary natural number for which we have such a representation. By the first lemma it is clear if there exists such a representation, then there exist infinitely many.

Now it suffices to prove the existence of such a representation, and to do so we use induction:

We have such a representation for $n=1, 2, 3$ & $4$. (E.g. $2 = -1 -4 -9 + 16$.)

Now suppose $n$ to be a natural number greater than $4$.  We have $m = (m-4) + 4$, and the second lemma implies the assertion.

Comment: See [this introductory note](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on posting mathematical expressions with `MathJax` and $\LaTeX$.